# Standalone Android Toolchain Gcc set include path

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, cross-compiling

Good day everyone.
I have some c code which I want to compile into shared libraries for android. I create a standalone toolchain but the resulting "gcc" doesn't accept/ignores my the "-I/home/user/directory" statement. Is there any way to tell the compiler include and/or lib paths?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't accept"?

Comment: Sorry for my bad choice of words. The compiler is complaining about "undefined references" which can't be the case. I've set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LIBRARY_PATH and C_INCLUDE_PATH. I've also set the command line arguments explicitly via "-I" and -"L" to the correct directories.